# How do I catch integrity errors in pyramid / sqlalchemy / pyramid_tm

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am trying to create a form to edit a user account. 
This code is for a user that already exists.

As you can see, I have put in a return statement before the try/catch.
This will generate the expected integrity exception when a username already exists.

However if I comment that out and let it go into the try/catch block, no exception is generated, it simply redirects to the HTTPFound with no error.
the call to flush does nothing.

```
if form.validate():

        user.username = form.username.data

        if form.password.data != "":
            user.password = encrypt(form.password.data)

        user.is_active = form.is_active.data
        user.email = form.email.data
        user.groups = form.groups.data

        # if i return here i will get integrity error as expected
        #return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('user_details', id=user.id))

        with transaction.manager as tx:
            try:
                request.sqldb.flush()
                # no exception is generated here
                return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('user_details', id=user.id))
            except IntegrityError as e:
                tx.abort()
                if 'UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username' in str(e):
                    form.username.errors.append('Username already exists')
                else:
                    errors.append('Integrity Error')
```

**edit**
here is the code that works
the transaction manager part was not even required:

```
        user.username = form.username.data

        if form.password.data != "":
            user.password = encrypt(form.password.data)

        user.is_active = form.is_active.data
        user.email = form.email.data
        user.groups = form.groups.data

        try:  
            request.sqldb.flush()  
            return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('user_details', id=user.id))
        except IntegrityError as e:
            if '(IntegrityError) duplicate key value' in str(e):
                errors.append('Username already exists')
            else:
                errors.append('Integrity Error')

            request.sqldb.rollback()
```

Comment: it should generate an exception in the try catch but it isnt

Comment: yep its the sqlalchemy session

Comment: Im changing the username to something that i know should generate an integrity error. When it hits the first return, i get the exception. But when i let it go into the try catch, there is no exception.

Comment: it has no effect, yes i did try it un-commented

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the model, and do changes to the model objects within the transaction manager, otherwise the session's `flush()` has a limited scope. The SQLAlchemy is smart enough to try to flush only that subset of changes that occur within the context manager. Thus:

```
with transaction.manager as tx:
    try:
        user = .... # get the user
        user.username = form.username.data

        if form.password.data != "":
            user.password = encrypt(form.password.data)

        user.is_active = form.is_active.data
        user.email = form.email.data
        user.groups = form.groups.data

        request.sqldb.flush()
        # no exception is generated here
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('user_details', id=user.id))
    except IntegrityError as e:
        tx.abort()
        if 'UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username' in str(e):
            form.username.errors.append('Username already exists')
        else:
            errors.append('Integrity Error')
```

Comment: this answer is not helpful at all, i fully explained that in the question

Comment: @mobiletim I tested the behaviour of `t.manager()` and it is as above

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on global exception handling.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html

```
from pyramid.view as view
import sqlalchemy.exc

@view.view_config(context=sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError, renderer='json')
def integrity_error(exc, request):
    request.response.status_code = 400
    return {
        'error': exc.orig.args[1]
    }
```

or

```
@view.exception_view_config(sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError, renderer='json')
def integrity_error(exc, request):
    request.response.status_code = 400
    return {
        'error': exc.orig.args[1]
    }
```

The differernce is described at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html

In this way, I can get a RESTful Api from Pyramid. It is rough, but useful in fast prototyping, and can save lots of code in routes.